# Using wget to recursively fetch a directory with arbitrary files in it

Tags: shell, wget

I have a web directory where I store some config files. I'd like to use wget to pull those files down and maintain their current structure. For instance, the remote directory looks like:

```
http://mysite.com/configs/.vim/
```

.vim holds multiple files and directories. I want to replicate that on the client using wget. Can't seem to find the right combo of wget flags to get this done. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1194, accepted):

You have to pass the `-np`/`--no-parent` option to `wget` (in addition to `-r`/`--recursive`, of course), otherwise it will follow the link in the directory index on my site to the parent directory. So the command would look like this:

```
wget --recursive --no-parent http://example.com/configs/.vim/
```

To avoid downloading the auto-generated `index.html` files, use the `-R`/`--reject` option:

```
wget -r -np -R "index.html*" http://example.com/configs/.vim/
```

Comment: add -nH (cuts out hostname) --cut-dirs=X (cuts out X directories). it's a bit annoying to have to manually count directories for X..

Comment: Why doesn't any of these work for http://www.w3.org/History/1991-WWW-NeXT/Implementation/ ?

It will only download robots.txt

Comment: @matteo because the robots.txt probably disallow crawling the website. You should add -e robots=off to force crawling.

Comment: add -X /absolute/path/to/folder to exclude a particular directory

Comment: If you don't want to download the entire content, you may use:

-l1 just download the directory (example.com in your case)

-l2 download the directory and all level 1 subfolders ('example.com/something' but not 'example.com/somthing/foo')  
And so on. If you insert no -l option, wget will use -l 5 automatically.

If you insert a -l 0 you´ll download the whole Internet, because wget will follow every link it finds. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19695143/6785908

Comment: `--no-parent` is most likely not needed for FTP downloads.

Comment: on macosx, this still grabs the directory structure.  @sriram's answer works best.

Comment: why am I always getting an index.html file instead of the directory?
`wget -r --no-parent -e robots=off http://demo.inspiretheme.com/templates/headlines/images/` This command will only get an index.html file

Comment: Additionally you can use combined with --accept or --reject, to only download specific file types

Comment: What if I am downloading from an SVN location using wget and that directory already has `index.html` files inside some directories. Is there a way to ommit automatically generating `index.html` and fetch exactly what is available (including the original existing `index.html` files)?

Answer (score 144):

To download a directory recursively, which rejects index.html* files and downloads without the hostname, parent directory and the whole directory structure :

```
wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=2 --no-parent --reject="index.html*" http://mysite.com/dir1/dir2/data
```

Comment: I can't get this to work:
wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=3 --no-parent --reject="index.html*" http://www.w3.org/History/1991-WWW-NeXT/Implementation/
--cut-dirs=2 doesn't work either
It only downloads robots.txt which actually is in the root folder. Whet am I missing?

Comment: @matteo try adding: -e robots=off

Comment: To recursively obtain all the directories within a directory, use wget -r -nH --reject="index.html*" http://mysite.io:1234/dir1/dir2

Answer (score 125):

For anyone else that having similar issues. Wget follows `robots.txt` which might not allow you to grab the site. No worries, you can turn it off:

```sh
wget -e robots=off http://www.example.com/
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Robot-Exclusion.html

Comment: When you are ignoring robots.txt you should at least throttle your requests. The behaviour suggested in this answer is highly impolite.

Comment: @Nobody So what's the polite answer to this?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij Rate limit your requests, wget has parameters for it. Note that some people might still take issue, and considering the robots file is explicitly telling you that it's not allowed to do what you are currently doing, you might even get into legal trouble.

Comment: I ran into an unhelpful robots.txt file while trying this out, but found a way around it without this option: the files I needed were also hosted on an FTP server, and running wget in mirror mode on the FTP server worked fine.

Answer (score 46):

You should use the -m (mirror) flag, as that takes care to not mess with timestamps and to recurse indefinitely.

```
wget -m http://example.com/configs/.vim/
```

If you add the points mentioned by others in this thread, it would be:

```
wget -m -e robots=off --no-parent http://example.com/configs/.vim/
```

Answer (score 41):

Here's the complete wget command that worked for me to download files from a server's directory (ignoring `robots.txt`):

```
wget -e robots=off --cut-dirs=3 --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 --reject="index.html*" --no-parent --recursive --relative --level=1 --no-directories http://www.example.com/archive/example/5.3.0/
```

Comment: this didn't download all subdirectories for me

Answer (score 17):

First of all, thanks to everyone who posted their answers. Here is my "ultimate" wget script to download a website recursively:

```sh
wget --recursive ${comment# self-explanatory} \
  --no-parent ${comment# will not crawl links in folders above the base of the URL} \
  --convert-links ${comment# convert links with the domain name to relative and uncrawled to absolute} \
  --random-wait --wait 3 --no-http-keep-alive ${comment# do not get banned} \
  --no-host-directories ${comment# do not create folders with the domain name} \
  --execute robots=off --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 ${comment# I AM A HUMAN!!!} \
  --level=inf  --accept '*' ${comment# do not limit to 5 levels or common file formats} \
  --reject="index.html*" ${comment# use this option if you need an exact mirror} \
  --cut-dirs=0 ${comment# replace 0 with the number of folders in the path, 0 for the whole domain} \
$URL
```

Afterwards, [stripping the query params](https://superuser.com/questions/61025/how-can-i-make-wget-rename-downloaded-files-to-not-include-the-query-string) from URLs like `main.css?crc=12324567` and running a local server (e.g. via `python3 -m http.server` in the dir you just wget'ed) to run JS may be necessary. Please note that the `--convert-links` option kicks in only after the full crawl was completed.

Also, if you are trying to wget a website that may go down soon, you should [get in touch with the ArchiveTeam](https://www.archiveteam.org/index.php?title=ArchiveBot) and ask them to add your website to their ArchiveBot queue.

Comment: Thanks, @berezovskyi, this helped me get started *really* quickly.

Comment: Would you suggest any update to this command with the `-m` mirror option, @berezovskyi ?

Comment: @NeilG I don't recall why I ended up expanding `--mirror` into `--recursive --level=inf`, but I think it was interfering with some option (`--no-parent` or `--cut-dirs=0`, perhaps)? According to `man`, `--mirror` is `... currently equivalent to -r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing.`

Comment: Thanks @berezogzkyi, I've had opportunity to use it a few different ways since then and I also found I didn't actually want to use the `--mirror` option - but I can't remember why, either, lol. Just one of the packed options wasn't suitable. Regards.

Answer (score 11):

If `--no-parent` not help, you might use `--include` option.

Directory struct:

```
http://<host>/downloads/good
http://<host>/downloads/bad
```

And you want to download `downloads/good` but not `downloads/bad` directory:

```
wget --include downloads/good --mirror --execute robots=off --no-host-directories --cut-dirs=1 --reject="index.html*" --continue http://<host>/downloads/good
```

Answer (score 8):

```
wget -r http://mysite.com/configs/.vim/
```

works for me.

Perhaps you have a .wgetrc which is interfering with it?

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you're trying to get a mirror of your file. While `wget` has some interesting FTP and SFTP uses, a simple mirror should work. Just a few considerations to make sure you're able to download the file properly.

### Respect `robots.txt`

Ensure that if you have a `/robots.txt` file in your `public_html`, `www`, or `configs` directory it does not prevent crawling. If it does, you need to instruct `wget` to ignore it using the following option in your `wget` command by adding:

```sh
wget -e robots=off 'http://your-site.com/configs/.vim/'
```

### Convert remote links to local files.

Additionally, `wget` must be **instructed** to convert links into downloaded files. If you've done everything above correctly, you should be fine here. The easiest way I've found to get all files, provided nothing is hidden behind a non-public directory, is using the `mirror` command.

#### Try this:

```sh
wget -mpEk 'http://your-site.com/configs/.vim/'

# If robots.txt is present:

wget -mpEk robots=off 'http://your-site.com/configs/.vim/'

# Good practice to only deal with the highest level directory you specify (instead of downloading all of `mysite.com` you're just mirroring from `.vim`

wget -mpEk robots=off --no-parent 'http://your-site.com/configs/.vim/'
```

Using `-m` instead of `-r` is preferred as it doesn't have a maximum recursion depth and it downloads all assets. Mirror is pretty good at determining the full depth of a site, however if you have many external links you could end up downloading more than just your site, which is why we use `-p -E -k`. All pre-requisite files to make the page, and a preserved directory structure should be the output. `-k` converts links to local files.
Since you should have a link set up, you should get your config folder with a file `/.vim`.

Mirror mode also works with a directory structure that's set up as an `ftp://` also.

#### General rule of thumb:

Depending on the side of the site you are doing a mirror of, you're sending many calls to the server. In order to prevent you from being blacklisted or cut off, use the `wait` option to rate-limit your downloads.

```sh
wget -mpEk --no-parent robots=off --random-wait 'http://your-site.com/configs/.vim/'
```

But if you're simply downloading the `../config/.vim/` file you shouldn't have to worry about it as your ignoring parent directories and downloading a single file.

Answer (score 5):

To fetch a directory recursively with username and password, use the following command:

```
wget -r --user=(put username here) --password='(put password here)' --no-parent http://example.com/
```

Answer (score 5):

This version downloads recursively and doesn't create parent directories.

```
wgetod() {
    NSLASH="$(echo "$1" | perl -pe 's|.*://[^/]+(.*?)/?$|\1|' | grep -o / | wc -l)"
    NCUT=$((NSLASH > 0 ? NSLASH-1 : 0))
    wget -r -nH --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 --cut-dirs=$NCUT --no-parent --reject="index.html*" "$1"
}
```

Usage:

1. Add to `~/.bashrc` or paste into terminal
2. `wgetod "http://example.com/x/"`

Answer (score 5):

The following option seems to be the perfect combination when dealing with recursive download:

wget  -nd -np -P /dest/dir --recursive http://url/dir1/dir2

Relevant snippets from man pages for convenience:

```
   -nd
   --no-directories
       Do not create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving recursively.  With this option turned on, all files will get saved to the current directory, without clobbering (if a name shows up more than once, the
       filenames will get extensions .n).


   -np
   --no-parent
       Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively.  This is a useful option, since it guarantees that only the files below a certain hierarchy will be downloaded.
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need is two flags, one is `"-r"` for recursion and `"--no-parent"` (or `-np`) in order not to go in the `'.'` and `".."`  . Like this:

`wget -r --no-parent http://example.com/configs/.vim/`

That's it. It will download into the following local tree: `./example.com/configs/.vim` .
However if you do not want the first two directories, then use the additional flag `--cut-dirs=2` as suggested in earlier replies:

`wget -r --no-parent --cut-dirs=2 http://example.com/configs/.vim/`

And it will download your file tree only into `./.vim/`

In fact, I got the first line from this answer precisely from the [wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Directory_002dBased-Limits), they have a very clean example towards the end of section 4.3.

Answer (score 2):

Wget 1.18 may work better, e.g., I got bitten by a version 1.12 bug where...

```
wget --recursive (...)
```

...only retrieves index.html instead of all files.

Workaround was to notice some 301 redirects and try the new location — given the new URL, wget got all the files in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive wget ignoring robots (for websites)

```
wget -e robots=off -r -np --page-requisites --convert-links 'http://example.com/folder/'
```

-e robots=off causes it to ignore robots.txt for that domain

-r makes it recursive

-np = no parents, so it doesn't follow links up to the parent folder

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it simply by adding a -r

```
wget -r http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Comment: This doesn't really download a directory, but all files that it can find on the server, including directories above the one you want to download.