# How to count files in https?

Tags: php, https, ftp

Is it possible to count files under a directory when you're only reading to https url? or only possible through ftp?

Comment: depends on the site, if directory listing is enabled, yes, but its probably not the best method.

Comment: ... and even if directory listing is "enabled" - it still could show something different rather than directory listing. So I'd say it is impossible due to inability to trust the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Only through `ftp`

`http` & `https` are protocols to view web applications. Features like `directory listing` are done from server, not through such protocols.

#### Explanation in case of php & apache server

When you are using commands like `scandir()` to read file and directory, its the server that does the reading for you. not any `http` or `https` link. The page you browse through such protocols will only deliver the output markup on the page.

Through these protocols, all files except server-side files can be delivered on their actual format.

Comment: @Ryan: I didn't do that but probably because http and https can serve files perfectly

Comment: oh I see. but is there php function that counts files through ftp?

Comment: I guess maybe if you consider that if directory listing is enabled you could sit there and count the files. Other than that no clue.

Comment: @jprofitt: how can you be sure that directory listing is a real directory listing? ;-)

Comment: Even FTP can fake the file count (although it usually doesn't).

Comment: @zerkms, How can you deliver files like `.php` through `http` or `https`? It will be parsed first. Right? Am I missing something?

Comment: @jprofitt: Yep, a bit. But put this http://pastebin.com/smbTsWHZ as an index.html and magically every directory will be empty... :-S

Comment: @Starx: you're missing a lot of other file types that are delivered as-is. It is just a rare exception that `.php` is pre-processed before sent back (and only in case if web server is configured for doing so)

Comment: @zerkms,I know every server script is pre-processed and everything else is delivered as is. But the directory listings is something a server does, not the `http` or `https`.

Comment: @Starx: Well, http and https don't do anything themselves. All the work is done by web server. And the phrase `http & https are used to browse web application not files.` is a bit incorrect, by definition

Comment: @zerkms, I see where I step out-of-bounds. Hope you like the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Typically directory listings are disabled on websites.

wget can be used crawl a site.
[Using wget to recursively fetch a directory with arbitrary files in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273743/using-wget-to-recursively-fetch-a-directory-with-arbitrary-files-in-it)

If directory listings aren't disabled on a site then you could download the page and parse the html to get the file count.

Comment: "Typically directory listings are disabled on websites." --- and even if it is "enabled" - you never can be sure that it is the real listing, not just a fake response