# How to download an entire directory and subdirectories using wget?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, wget

I am trying to download the files for a project using `wget`, as the SVN server for that project isn't running anymore and I am only able to access the files through a browser. The base URLs for all the files is the same like

> http://abc.tamu.edu/projects/tzivi/repository/revisions/2/raw/tzivi/*

How can I use `wget` (or any other similar tool) to download all the files in this repository, where the "tzivi" folder is the root folder and there are several files and sub-folders (upto 2 or 3 levels) under it?

Comment: You can't do that if server has no web-page with list of all links to files you need.

Comment: do you know the name of the files?

Comment: no i don't know the name of all files.I tried wget with the recursive option but it didn't work either.Is that because the server doesn't have any index.html file which lists all the inner links.

Comment: Did you try the mirroring option of wget?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

You may use this in shell:

```
wget -r --no-parent http://abc.tamu.edu/projects/tzivi/repository/revisions/2/raw/tzivi/
```

The Parameters are:

```
-r     //recursive Download
```

and

```
--no-parent // Don´t download something from the parent directory
```

If you don't want to download the entire content, you may use:

```
-l1 just download the directory (tzivi in your case)

-l2 download the directory and all level 1 subfolders ('tzivi/something' but not 'tivizi/somthing/foo')
```

And so on. If you insert no `-l` option, `wget` will use `-l 5` automatically.

If you insert a `-l 0` you´ll download the whole Internet, because `wget` will follow every link it finds.

Comment: Great, so to simplify for the next reader: `wget -r -l1 --no-parent http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/cvxbook_additional_exercises/` was the answer for me. Thanks your answer.

Comment: I tried the above command to get all the files from `http://websitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05` but all I got was an `index.html` file which had nothing. I can't figure what I missed.

Comment: @up: Note that wget follows links, so you need a directory listing ;)

Comment: @greensn0w is it possible to use the same coding for also https links which requires username & password? Does it work if I just add https://username:password@xxx.com/etc... at the beginning of the code?

Comment: I know this is quite old. But what I also found useful was the `-e robots=off` switch. ;)

Comment: @sn0w is -l 1 only supposed to download the target folder without subdirectories?

Comment: It's really really important the last slash at the end of the URL, without it, it will download anything recursevily

Comment: Why don't you remove the "I forgot something important" and just fix the answer ???

Comment: We can use -nH option with wget to prevent the hostname directory getting created by default with the download directory.

Comment: In addition to -nH to prevent hostname directory being created, use `--cut-dirs=x` to cut the first `x` directories past the hostname from being created in the download directory

Answer (score 27):

You can use this in a shell:

```
wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=7 --reject="index.html*" \
      http://abc.tamu.edu/projects/tzivi/repository/revisions/2/raw/tzivi/
```

The Parameters are:

```
-r recursively download

-nH (--no-host-directories) cuts out hostname 

--cut-dirs=X (cuts out X directories)
```

Answer (score 11):

[This link](https://www.tupp.me/2014/06/how-to-crawl-website-with-linux-wget.html) just gave me the best answer:

```
$ wget --no-clobber --convert-links --random-wait -r -p --level 1 -E -e robots=off -U mozilla http://base.site/dir/
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: Where to use this code?

Answer (score 5):

use the command

```
wget -m www.ilanni.com/nexus/content/
```

Answer (score 5):

```
wget -r --no-parent URL --user=username --password=password
```

the last two options are optional if you have the username and password for downloading, otherwise no need to use them.

You can also see more options in the link https://www.howtogeek.com/281663/how-to-use-wget-the-ultimate-command-line-downloading-tool/

Answer (score 2):

you can also use this command :

```
wget --mirror -pc --convert-links -P ./your-local-dir/ http://www.your-website.com
```

so that you get the exact mirror of the website you want to download

Answer (score 1):

**try this working code (30-08-2021):**

```
!wget --no-clobber --convert-links --random-wait -r -p --level 1 -E -e robots=off --adjust-extension -U mozilla "yourweb directory with in quotations"
```

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
wget -m -np -c --no-check-certificate -R "index.html*" "https://the-eye.eu/public/AudioBooks/Edgar%20Allan%20Poe%20-%2"
```

Answer (score -1):

This will help

```
wget -m -np -c --level 0 --no-check-certificate -R"index.html*"http://www.your-websitepage.com/dir
```

Comment: A little description of your suggested answer will be more helpful. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer