# wget recursive image download - error 404

Tags: image, recursion, download, wget

I want to download all the png images in http://media.pldh.net/pokemon/go/ directory with wget. I am sure there are images in the directory: http://media.pldh.net/pokemon/go/bulbasaur.png
This is what i use:

```
wget -r -nd -np -A.png http://media.pldh.net/pokemon/go/
```

This is the output:

```
--2016-08-06 13:46:20--  http://media.pldh.net/pokemon/go/
Resolving media.pldh.net (media.pldh.net)... 192.185.70.249
Connecting to media.pldh.net (media.pldh.net)|192.185.70.249|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-08-06 13:46:21 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Is it possible use wget to download recursively all the images?

Comment: check out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282915/download-an-entire-directory-using-wget

Comment: I've already used this flag. Not working.