# How to download all files from hidden directory

Tags: bash, shell, wget, csh

I have do download all log files from a virtual directory within a site. The access to virtual directory is forbidden but files are accessible.

I have manually entered the file names to download

```
dir="Mar"
for ((i=1;i<100;i++)); do
   wget http://sz.dsyn.com/2014/$dir/log_$i.txt
done
```

The problem is the script is not generic and most of the time I need to find out how many files are there and tweak the for loop. Is there a way to trigger wget to fetch all files without me bothering to specify the exact count.

Note:
If I use the browser to view http://sz.dsyn.com/2014/$dir, it is 403 forbidden. I cant pull all the files via browser tool/extension.

Comment: Is there a realistic maximum? Why not just loop to a high number? If it fails, it'll fail quickly and you can just ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273743/using-wget-to-recursively-fetch-a-directory-with-arbitrary-files-in-it?rq=1) If this is not what you are looking for, you need to generate a file of URLs within and feed `wget`. e.g.

```
 wget --input-file=http://sz.dsyn.com/2014/$dir/filelist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

wget will have the same problem your browser has:  it cannot read the directory.  Just pull until your first failure then quit.