# unix command to copy file from one server to another

Tags: unix

I need to copy a file from one server to another. Here is my exact requirement. I am log in from server a and I have to copy a file from server b to server c . So what is the command for it ?

Comment: If you has access of the ftp of the remote server, we can also use **wget** to download like `$wget -r --level=9 --no-parent --reject "index.html*" ftp://<USERID>:<PASSWORD>@<MACHINE-NAME>/path/to` [Reference1](http://kspace.in/blog/2010/02/22/copy-files-using-wget/) [Reference2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/273776/3049065)

Answer (score 1):

```
scp <FILES> <USER>@<HOST_IP_OR_NAME>:<DIRECTORY>
```

http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp

Assuming you can log in to server b run the command above and `HOST_IP_OR_NAME` is server c

Comment: Sir the above command will not work for my condition. I am log in from  server a and i have to copy a file from server b to server c. Thanks

Comment: Do you have user/pass for server b?

Comment: Yes. I have the user/pass

Comment: then log in to server B and copy to server C from there :) telnet or ssh supposingly are enabled ... if not you have to ftp locally (to machine A (from B) and from A to C :( )