# Downloading index of/ .*php files

Tags: php, server, penetration-testing

I have a link like that: http://example.com/_config/ 
This directory is not protected, so i can see all files like e.g config.php etc.

Aaaand here's the question: I'm able to download and see this *.php files?
I was trying my best, by using wget/curl, but i'm always getting empty .php file.

Is there any chance to download this files?

Comment: The php files will probably get interpreted first before it's sent to you. Since those are config files, they most probably don't print anything. Which is why you're probably getting empty files supposing you're fetching them correctly. Otherwise check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273743/using-wget-to-recursively-fetch-a-directory-with-arbitrary-files-in-it

Answer (score 0):

You can't download the source of "php" file from the browsers (wysiwyg or textbase, same result) like that. Those files would be processed when you request them and you'll always get the rendered (html output) version unless some misconfiguration on the server side.