# How to get the list of folder/file names from a url using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Here is a sample website url with a list of folders; I need to get these folder names stored using shell / bash script

[image]

Comment: try using `wget` with the recursive option? https://stackoverflow.com/a/273776/1681480

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
curl <url> | grep -oP '<a href=".+?">\K.+?(?=<)'
```

Mac:

```
curl <url> | perl -nle 'print $& while m{<a href=".+?">\K.+?(?=<)}g'
```

It might need some tweaking for your specific site.