# How to download all the files along with all the sub-directories from a server using wget in Linux?

Tags: wget

I know this question has been asked many times, but the answers didn't help me anything. 
[Server link from where I'm trying to download files](https://lol.freecoronavirus.workers.dev/[zerotomastery.io]ZERO%20TO%20MASTERY%202020%20COLLECTION/[zerotomastery.io]ZERO%20TO%20MASTERY%202020%20COLLECTION/Complete%20Machine%20Learning%20and%20Data%20Science%20Zero%20to%20Mastery%202020-4/March%20Update%20old%202020-3/)

I'm trying to download all the sub-folders and all the files listed into them from the above link. But the problem is, whenever I use wget, it downloads either an index file only, or some sub-folders that ends up with nothing. I've tried following [THIS discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273743/using-wget-to-recursively-fetch-a-directory-with-arbitrary-files-in-it/273776#273776), but end up with empty handed.

It might be that I didn't understood how to use them, that's why I provided the link to the server so that anyone can help me. Thanks in advance!

(The previous directory of the given server link has the files in rar format, but those rar files are actually broken)

Answer (score 0):

Wget will not be able to help you here, as the link you've posted uses JavaScript to generate its contents.

You would need to use a web scraper that parses JavaScript, and THEN pull out any URLs or paths from it.

One example I could point you to is [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) and [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)