# linux tar command for remote machine

Tags: linux, centos, tar, rhel5

How can I create a `.tar` archive of a file (say `/root/bugzilla`) on a remote machine and store it on a local machine. SSH-KEYGEN is installed, so I can by pass authentication.

I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
tar -zcvf Localmachine_bugzilla.tar.gz /root/bugzilla
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote Linux server to remote linux server dir copy. How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69411/remote-linux-server-to-remote-linux-server-dir-copy-how)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ssh <host> tar -zcvf - /root/bugzilla > bugzilla.tar.gz
```

avoids an intermediary copy.

See also this post for a couple of variants: [Remote Linux server to remote linux server dir copy. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69411/remote-linux-server-to-remote-linux-server-dir-copy-how)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
ssh <host> tar -zcvf bugzilla.tar.gz /root/bugzilla
scp <host>:bugzilla.tar.gz Localmachine_bugzilla.tar.gz
```

Or, if you are compressing it just for the sake of transfer, `scp` compression option can be useful:

```
scp -R -C <host>:/root/bugzilla .
```

This is going to copy the whole `/root/bugzilla` directory using compression on the wire.